# Space and Time Consumption of (Custom) Performance Counters

Tags: .net, windows, performance, performancecounter, interlocked

In terms of the speed of incrementing a (custom) performance counter, I understand performance counters to be lock-free, processor primitives.  I suspect this means they can execute in the space of a few dozen CPU cycles - which means they are so fast, they virtually impossible to benchmark.  Correct?

In terms of the memory consumption of creating a custom performance counter, I've heard from a colleague that they require about 128kb or more per counter (from global shared, or seperate shared memory).  I can't believe that number.  It makes very little sense.  I could perhaps believe 2k to 8k, but I'd like to know if anyone has more accurate information on this?